# Convert a c# decimal to big-endian byte array

Tags: c#, .net, bitwise, apache-kafka

Following the [avro schema documentation for decimals](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Decimal) I've created a method to turn a decimal into a byte array. The goals are:

1. Should be represented by a non-scaled integer
2. Should be big-endian

I've tested the code I wrote, but I'd like to know if the program still works in any unforeseen corner cases.

```csharp
private static byte[] ToBigEndianByteArray(decimal value, int scale)
{
    var bigInteger = new BigInteger(value * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, scale));
    var bytes = bigInteger.ToByteArray();
    return BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? bytes.Reverse().Select(ReverseEndianness).ToArray() : bytes;

    static byte ReverseEndianness(byte input)
    {
        const int bits = 8;
        return (byte)Enumerable.Range(0, bits - 1)
            .Aggregate(0, (accumulator, index) =>
                BitAtIndexIsSet(input, index)
                    ? SetBitAtIndex(accumulator, bits - 1 - index)
                    : accumulator);

        static int SetBitAtIndex(int value, int index) => value | 1 << index;
        static bool BitAtIndexIsSet(int value, int index) => (value & (1 << index)) != 0;
    }
}
```

Example usage: `ToBigEndianByteArray(8.45m, 2)` produces `0000001101001101` (845 in decimal).

Comment: Here we can review code which works as expected. So, asking a question like this *someone could tell me if this looks correct or not* does indicate that you are not sure whether it works as expected.

Comment: BTW why do you have so many nested static local functions?

Comment: @PeterCsala as far as I can see I followed the spec and it seems to produce the correct output. This may not be the goal of the site, but I'd expect a code review to cover whether the code actually does what it intends to.
As to your second question I've scoped them to the only place that they're used.

Comment: BTW for me the function returned `[192, 178]` which, as a big-endian integer, would correspond to 256 * 192 + 178 = 49330 which I don't think is what you want. You can read the result as 845 if you interpret the bits in an unusual way, so I can see where you got it, but I don't think that's right.

Comment: @PeterCsala With the given explanation, it's fine. Code doesn't have to be perfect, it has to work to the best of the authors knowledge. That seems to be the case.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look correct to me, in two ways:

1. Computing `Math.Pow(10, scale)`. This is not exact when scale is negative or large. Since it's fine for moderate positive scales and the amount of inexactness in other cases typically won't be very high, it may be difficult to actually produce a wrong result, but I would not dare to rely on it - especially for a format that is supposed to be exact.
2. Big-endian does not mean reversing the bits in every byte, which I *think* the `ReverseEndianness` does, but it's a relatively confusing function, and I don't mean the bitwise part of it but rather everything *except* that. I would have used [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602885/555045) adapted for C#. Doesn't really matter in the end, because the specification does not say to reverse the bits to begin with, so you can remove that whole function.

Furthermore I think the API is hard to use correctly, because it assumes that you already have a scale, which is not trivial to find. Passing the wrong scale can very easily result in information being lost.

Alternatively, you may be able to use the [GetBits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=net-6.0) method on the decimal, extract its internal scale (and use it directly as the scale in avro format, which uses the same kind of scales), and convert the integer part that it has internally to a big-endian (but not bit-reversed) array of bytes. It seems to me that this would severely limit the possibility of both incorrect API usage, and incorrect implementation.

Comment: > Alternatively, you may be able to use the GetBits method on the decimal, extract its internal scale

I'm not sure about this, the schema is static and the input values for the fields shouldn't be changing scale. How do you suppose to do that dynamically?


> Big-endian does not mean reversing the bits in every byte, which I think the ReverseEndianness does

I'm struggling to understand this. At first I just reversed the byte array, but then thought that can't possibly be correct.

Comment: @NickL if the scale is fixed then please ignore that suggestion. As for big-endian, reversing the bytes (but not the bits within them) is right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'd been running `string.Join("", bytes.SelectMany(b => new BitArray(new[] { b }).Cast<bool>()).Select(b => b ? 1 : 0))`.
My rationale was that it was reversing a collection of collections of bits. If only the outer collection was reversed, then each inner collection would need to be reversed too

Comment: I totally agree `decimal.GetBits` should be used. I can comment on `Math.Pow`. As I explained in [an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474852/), powers of ten generally cannot be exact in a `double`. Try for example `(1e23).ToString("G17")` or `Math.Pow(10.0, 23.0).ToString("G17")`. The subsequent cast from `double` to `decimal` can lose precision again in a way that can actually save you, but it is fragile! There is `BigInteger.Pow` which is exact.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks for the information. I don't believe I can use `decimal.GetBits` because it has to match the schema, which is set at design time. I will look at using `BigInteger.Pow`, but realistically I doubt scales that high would ever be used.

Comment: @NickL Conside something like `var int64s = decimal.GetBits(value); var significandBytes = int64s.Take(3).SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).Reverse().ToArray();`. The first three 32-bit integers in the array from `.GetBits` gives you the significand (or "unscaled" value). If you care about the sign (positive or negative) or the position of the decimal point (so-called scale) of the `value`, you can get that from the last 32-bit integer.